# Server 2019 OpenSSH SFTP server only allows Admin group

Tags: openssh, sftp, windows-server

We set up an SFTP server using the OpenSSH feature in Windows Server 2019 following the instructions on the WinSCP website.  It works, but it only allows Domain Administrator profiles to access.  We have tried activating the AllowUsers and AllowGroups keywords in the sshd_config file to no avail.  I had this working on our Windows 2012R2 server using the downloaded OpenSSH package and I do not recall needing to modify the default sshd_config file.  Has anyone else run into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is my stab at this and hopes this works for the ones that have been at this for a while. Add your sftp windows box to the "RAS and IAS Servers" group in the domain. This was an issue when I was bringing up RDG.